# Android studio keeps jumping over/not hitting breakpoints

Tags: android, android-studio, android-studio-3.0

I'm experiencing random behavior in android studio (4.1.1). When hitting debug (`Shift + F9`) the first breakpoints are being hit but sometimes when stepping through code (`F8`), there is some lag and chunks of 5, 10 lines are jumped over in quick succession.

Sometimes, when resuming execution (`F9`), breakpoints that are supposed to be hit (button handlers (same buttons pressed)) are no longer hit even they were hit on the first run.

I thought it to be related to win defender scanning(hooking writes to) the project dir but it seems that's not the case.

Anyone else struggling with this?

Comment: In general terms, this sounds like you are debugging against a different version of the code than you are looking at. I have no Android experience and does not know if there is an issue there.

Comment: Hm... I tried rebuilding/reimporting gradle dependencies/deleting app before rerun but it seems to persist.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It may be caused by code running on different threads. Right click on the breakpoint and switch from Thread to All, see the screenshot below.

[image: breakpoint thread]